# Single serialization layer to Json with Casbah/Salat

Tags: json, mongodb, casbah, salat

I am trying to create a serialization layer which allows me to:

- Store my classes in a MongoDB data source
- Convert them to JSON to use them in a REST API.

Some classes are clearly not case classes (because they are inherited from a Java codebase) and I would have to write ad-hoc code for that. Is registering a BSON Hook for my non standard type the correct approach, and does it provide Json serialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salat maintainer here.

You might prefer to create a Salat custom transformer instead of registering a BSON hook with Casbah.

See [simple example](https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/master/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/custom/model.scala) and [spec](https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/master/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/CustomTransformerSpec.scala).

If you run into any issues, feel free to ping the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-salat) with a small sample Github project that demonstrates what isn't working.

Comment: I verified that the transformer does not work if the input class is not a case class, so my problem is not solved yet. Would it make sense to write a CustomTransformer from a Java class to DBOBject directly?